# jQuery parent slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

Hello I made a fake load more for some elements in some divs. My problem is when i click on the **Load More** the jquery slice and load on click all my elements ( from my first container and second container ).

Here is my code and [**here is jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/327xr/):

```
$(".tohide").hide();
$(".tohide").slice(0, 3).show();

$(".more-comments").click(function(){
    var showing = $(".tohide:visible").length;
    $(".tohide").slice(showing - 1, showing + 999).show(); 
});
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: to work for each container, so when i click on load more button on the first container just the elements in the first container to show and i want to slice elements foreach container not all.

Comment: `id`s should always be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `next()` and `children()`, like this:

```
$(this).next("#comments").children(".tohide").slice(showing, showing + 999).show();
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/327xr/9/).

Comment: thank you, but if i click on the first load more button the other one dont work.

Comment: The `showing` variable should be constrained to the specific `.comments` container as well.

Comment: Updated fiddle to include `#comments` specificity: http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/327xr/4/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you try to be more clear about what it needs to do?

Comment: so on the first container and second container i need to have 3 items visible, when i click on the load more the items that are in the same container with the load more button that i clicked will be displayed. ty!

Comment: @user1670082 Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/327xr/9/ - it should display the first 3 of each now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `slice` inside `click`, try this:

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wp2k5/2/)

```
$(".more-comments").click(function(){
    $(this).next('.comments').children('.tohide').show();
});
```

and also note that `id`'s are uniqiue, don't use them on different elements. On your example it was `#comments`.

Comment: `showing` should be constrained to the specific `.comments` container as well.

Comment: thank you, but if i click on the first load more button the other one dont work.

Comment: thank you barlas but he dosent work 100% ok, the second container elements dont appears